# PubSub Dead Letter in a GCF

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

I have a google cloud function triggered by PubSub, and I'm trying to forward an execution with error to a dead letter topic.

I am forcing an error:

```js
throw Error('test')
```

And the function is finished with status error.
Ending a function with an error, should the message be forwarded to the Dead Letter topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you bind your Cloud Function with PubSub directly, I mean, you use the --trigger-topic option when you deploy, some PubSub feature aren't available. It's the case for the Dead Letter topic, for the filtering and for the ordering key for example .

If you want to use these features, you need to deploy your function as HTTP function and to call it with a PubSub push subscription that you can customize as you which.

Be careful, the format of PubSub message in a HTTP push function isn't exactly the same as background function. The function signature also change a bit. You need to rework a few on your code before achieving the change.

Comment: Great answer. Do you have some official info about that? Or is it a bug?

Comment: of which official info are you talking about?

Comment: Actually, the Dead Letter feature is available when binding CF with Pub/Sub. You just need to make sure the "Retry on Failure" is checked on the CF side.